# Fluid diodes for use with cryogens

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My aim is to measure the pressure difference across a fluid diode (a tube which allows a fluid to flow easily in one direction and with difficulty in the other direction). Is there an equation which relates flow rate to pressure for turbulent flow? (I cannot use a manometer because it will become too cold and break when used with cryogens)

Answer (score 4):

There's no theoretical method that will reliably predict how the cryogenic check valves will respond to flow/ pressure given the possibility of multiphase flow and that the check valve is a complex, active restriction. You really have to instrument your setup and take data. True a manometer will not work, but you can use cryogenic pressure transducers like the ones described [here](http://www.pcb.com/contentstore/docs/PCB_Corporate/Pressure/products/Manuals/102A14.pdf) on each side of the check valve to measure the pressure. And [cryogenic flow meters](http://www.hofferflow.com/cryogenics.asp) can also be used to measure the flow.